# $(3x- 3)\prod_{n = 1}^∞\frac{\exp(2^{-n})+1}{x^{2^{-n}}+1}=(x^3-1)\prod_{n = 1}^∞\frac{\exp(2^{-n})+1}{x^{3 \cdot 2^{-n}}+1}$

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

Show that

$$ (3x - 3) \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {x^{2^{-n}} + 1}
= (x^3 - 1) \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {x^{3\cdot2^{-n}} + 1} $$

Comment: The $g(n)$ in the title doesn't appear in the question body.  Please clarify this for me.

Comment: $g(n) = exp(2^{-n}) + 1 $. But that made the title too long.

Comment: What's the domain of $z?$  In particular is $z$ complex?

Comment: Yes $z$ is complex. But If you can show it for positive reals then it can be shown to work for complex $z$ by analytic continuation. I think that is the easiest way. Showing the analytic continuation is possible can be done by showing the function is analytic. Showing the function is analytic can be done ... but that is not the main question. An alternative strategy is with contour integrals but that is probably harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;
\left(x^{2^{-n}}-1\right) \cdot \left(x^{2^{-n}}+1\right)\left(x^{2^{-(n-1)}}+1\right)\ldots\left(x^{2^{-1}}+1\right) = x - 1
\,$ by telescoping.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  It then follows that the $\,n^{th}\,$ partial product on the LHS is:

$$\require{cancel}
3\cancel{(x - 1)} \cdot \frac{\left(x^{2^{-n}} - 1\right)}{\left(e^{2^{-n}} - 1\right)} \cdot \frac{\left(e^{2^{-n}} - 1\right) \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \left(e^{2^{-k}} +1\right)}{\cancel{\left(x^{2^{-n}} - 1\right)\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \left(x^{2^{-k}} +1\right)}} = 3(e-1) \cdot \frac{x^{2^{-n}} - 1}{e^{2^{-n}} - 1}
$$

For $\,n \to \infty\,$ $\,\,2^{-n} \to 0\,$, and the LHS therefore reduces to:

$$
\lim_{a \to 0} \,3(e-1) \cdot \frac{x^a - 1}{e^{a} - 1} = \ldots
$$

Comment: Im aware of that. I can prove the analogue case where 3 is replaced by 2 ...   but Im stuck with 3.

Comment: @mick I edited the next step in. But you should really post more context in/to the question, including what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Im still confused actually

Comment: @mick All that's left to do is calculate the limit on the last line, then redo the same steps on the RHS. Please try that, and if you get stuck at some particular step point out which one and why.

Comment: Ok I got it :) Thank u.