Is $f(x,d) = (x-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{1+d}{x^{1/2^n}+d}$ close to $\ln(x)^{g(d)}$?
Let $x,d$ be real numbers such that $x>1,d>-1$ and
$$f(x,d) = (x-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{1+d}{x^{1/2^n}+d}$$
Is it true that for all $d>1$ there exists an analytic function $g(d)$ such that
$$ l(d) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x,d)}{\ln(x)^{g(d)}} $$
always exists ?
It is easy to show that $f(x,-1) = 0$ and that $f(x,0) = \frac{x-1}{x}$.
It is also known that $f(x,1) = \ln(x)$ and therefore that $g(1) = 1$ as shown here :
Why do we have $ \ln(z) = \frac{z-1}{e -1} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {z^{2^{-n}} + 1} $
It appears that approximately
$$g(3) = 2$$
$$g(10) = 3$$
$$g(32) = 4$$
$$g(123) = 5$$
$$g(616) = 6$$
$$g(4339) = 7$$
where the $10,32,123,616,4339$ are rounded to below (floor).

edit
it seems that the following estimates are valid :
$$g(0,247783665..) = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$g(0,398681095..) = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$g(3,424560155..) = 2$$

Slightly related this other generalization : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977205/asymptotics-for-fz-z-1-prod-n-frac2z1-a-n1-with-1-a-1-1-a-2

And in a similar spirit : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653643/3x-3-prod-n-1%e2%88%9e-frac-exp2-n1x2-n1-x3-1-prod-n-1

I have a complicated idea... maybe more later
